# Rishi Viswamitra created a new heaven, could not produce food for him and his family?

Tags: devi, rishi, viswamitra

So i was reading srimad devi bhagavata purana in which its mentioned the story of Trisanku and sage viswamitra. in that story its stated sage viswamitra's family was living in raja Trisanku's kingdom when sage viswamitra went to the forest to do tapasya, leaving his wife and children. now due to poverty and famine sage viswamitra's wife and children had to go through a rough time when raja trisanku helped them by supplying meat as food. Sage viswamitra himself , after meeting up with his family some time later , explained to his wife how due to famine at that same time when his family was starving , he himself one day had to go steal some dog meat from the house of a chandala. Now interestingly later in this same story we hear how sage viswamitra used his powers of tapasya to create a new heaven for King trisanku when he Trisaku couldnt stay in heaven in his own human body and was thrown out from that.

So my question after all this story telling is simple this, If sage viswamitra , like all other munis and rishis of that time, had so much tapasya energy in him that he could create a new heaven , why didnt he use a little tiny bit of that tapasya energy to maybe produce some food for him during his days of "having to steal and eat from a chandala's house" levels of desperation that he faced during some of his days in tapasya in his forest?

Now i have a guess why he didnt use his powers to generate food. Maybe was because he didnt want to waste his tapasya power on something as trivial as producing food ,but I think this explanation fails since he was so desperate in this situation and it was a matter of life and death so much so that he resorted to stealing so that his body doesn't die of starvation, he himself explains to the chandala how ,according to wise people, stealing and eating food from a chandala's house was ok since there was a famine and during a famine , the sin of stealing and eating food at a chandala's house actually go to the person who prevented rains from appearing or who caused the famine , which would be lord indra.

But can somebody explain this sort of weird contradiction or incident as to why sage viswamitra didnt make food appear for him or maybe grow some small amount of rice or something using his tapasya power ?